# Attempting to log JSON response from REST API in JavaScript using Fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, response, jsonresponse

I have a small script that I have put together. The script does the following:

- Defines several variables within an array
- Passes those values to an API
- API should return an access token

  ```
   const fetch = require('node-fetch');
   var orgInfo = {
               client_id: 'idgoeshere', 
               client_secret: 'secretgoeshere', 
               username: 'usernamegoeshere', 
               password: 'passwordgoeshere', 
               grant_type: 'granttypegoeshere'
           };

   fetch('https://urlgoeshere', {
       method: "GET",
       body: JSON.stringify(orgInfo),
       headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },

   credentials: "include"

   }).then(function(response) {

   response.access_token
   response.bearer
   response.expires_in
   response.scope

   return repsonse.text()

   }, function(error) {
       error.message
   })

   console.log(orgInfo);
   console.log(response.access_token);
  ```

When I log orgInfo, I do get the following output:

```
{ client_id: 'idgoeshere',
  client_secret: 'secretgoeshere',
  username: 'usernamegoeshere',
  password: 'passwordgoeshere',
  grant_type: 'granttypegoeshere' }
```

When I try to log response.access_token, I get a **ReferenceError: response is not defined**

My questions are:

- Does response need to be defined? Obviously, Im being yelled at because it isnt.
- Is there a way to see if I am getting anything back from the API automagically?

Im not looking for someone to spoon-feed me an answer, rather I am simply looking for a push in the right direction. That would be stellar.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So this is what I have:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const orgInfo = {
client_id: ' ', 
client_secret: ' ', 
username: ' ', 
password: ' ', 
grant_type: ' '
};

(async() => {

const response =  await fetch('https:// ', {
    method: "GET",
    body: JSON.stringify(orgInfo),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});

const data = await response.json();
console.log(data)
})
```

This returns no errors when running but also doesnt return the value of **data**

Comment: I think you shouldn't be sending that "sensitive data" over a GET method, but instead use POST. You can't use the response variable after the fetch, but instead you must use it inside the then(response) block cause JavaScript default behavior, otherwise check await.  You should Google "fetch  post json example" and see what's the proper way to go about it. You can also use something like Postman, to test API calls, and then you can generate code from there for your desired language.

Comment: @Marty Doesn’t return since you’re not returning anything - return the value using the return keyword; why are you also wrapping in an async lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` returns a `Promise` object.

A `Promise` represents the *eventual* completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value. That means `response.access_token` is only guaranteed to have a value (if any) inside the `.then` block as `response` is only evaluated when the promise has been *fulfilled*.

**The reason you get nothing in the console is that you are trying to access `access_token` when it is not guaranteed to have a value (and thus `console.log` outputs nothing - there is *nothing to output*).**

---

To fix this, you need to access the `access_token` property when you are guaranteed to have a response.

That is after the promise has been fulfilled, so either:

1. Move the `console.log(response.access_token);` inside the `.then` clause

Or a cleaner, more modern solution would be to:

2. Use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (equivalent syntactical sugar)

---

N.B. The [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object is the representation of the *entire* HTTP response.

You're using [`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) which will parse the response body as a *string*, not a *JS object with properties*.

I'm assuming you want to parse the body content from the `Response` object as JSON into a JS object. In that case, use the [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method which will then return a 2nd promise resolving with the JavaScript object obtained from the parsing of the response body.

The result should have the `access_token` property you want (considering the API endpoint returns it).

This should work:

```
const response =  await fetch('https://urlgoeshere', {
     method: "GET",
     body: JSON.stringify(orgInfo),
     headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
 };

const data = await response.json();

console.log(data.access_token);
console.log(data.bearer);
console.log(data.expires_in);
console.log(data.scope);
...
```

Comment: Your response is much more explained. I appreciate that. If I am getting nothing back with the updated code, that would indicate I am not getting a response?

Comment: You also have a small bug - @MartyLavender I've now updated the answer with a working example + explanation. Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

#### return repsonse.text() should be ----> return response.text()

According to [Fetch Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

- "The Response interface of the Fetch API represents the response to a
  request. You **can** create a new Response object using the Response.Response() constructor, **but you are more likely to encounter a Response object being returned as the result of another API operation—for example,** a service worker Fetchevent.respondWith, **or a simple fetch().**

##### For your question "Is there a way to see if I am getting anything back from the API automagically?"

- You can try using **console.log(response.status);** which will give you the status code of your request. These codes can be found [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). And an example of this being used [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status).
- I highly recommend trying to use Postman or Thunder-client if you can which simplifies all of this and gives you everything you need to know about the response. It is very useful to test API calls and know exactly what is happening. You also have the ability to see your call written in other languages automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var orgInfo = {
             client_id: 'idgoeshere', 
             client_secret: 'secretgoeshere', 
             username: 'usernamegoeshere', 
             password: 'passwordgoeshere', 
             grant_type: 'granttypegoeshere'
};

fetch('https://urlgoeshere', {
     method: "GET",
     body: JSON.stringify(orgInfo),
     headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     credentials: "include"
}).then(function(response) {

     response.access_token
     response.bearer
     response.expires_in
     response.scope

     console.log(response.access_token);

     return repsonse.text()

 }, function(error) {
     error.message
 })

 console.log(orgInfo);
```

response ins scoped inside the function called by the then method so it is accessible only inside of this function

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you. Im not getting anything logged to the console at this point, so I have to assume that I am not getting a response?